# Android HttpPost doesnt't work

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, http-post

I have a mysql database on a localhost:88 called 'test' with a username 'root' and the table called 'example' in there.
I'm trying to get data on my android app using php script with method $_POST. But it just doesn't work normally and I can't understand why. Here's my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    TextView txt;
    EditText editText;
    ProgressBar pb;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if(editText.getText().toString().length()<1)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Enter something!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        else{
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new sendData().execute(editText.getText().toString());
        }
    }

    class sendData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>
    {
        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... strings) {
            postData(strings[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Double aDouble) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            pb.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/basicphp/setData.php");
            httpPost.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            try
            {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", valueIWantToSend));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                Log.d("postData","response" + response.getEntity());
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                Log.wtf("postData", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my php script:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '', 'test');    

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);

    $sql =  
    "INSERT INTO `example` (name) VALUES ("$name");";

    mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Error occured: ' . mysqli_error($con));

    echo 'Values inserted successfully!';

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

LOGCAT:

```
09-22 19:25:16.916    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-22 19:25:17.020    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-22 19:25:17.112    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
09-22 19:25:17.116    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9620558, tid 2170
09-22 19:25:17.132    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
09-22 19:25:17.132    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
09-22 19:25:17.220    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-22 19:25:17.256    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
09-22 19:25:24.400    2170-2170/my.com.jsontry W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-22 19:26:28.272    2170-2188/my.com.jsontry A/postData﹕ Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused
09-22 19:26:28.292    2170-2173/my.com.jsontry D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 111K, 9% free 2599K/2852K, paused 10ms+2ms, total 20ms
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong, so please, help me to understand what exactly and correct my mistakes. I've searched through similar questions but still haven't hit upon the answer. I'd really appreciate if you could explain all the stuff in more or less simple words 'cause I'm quite a newbie in android and php programming.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a mysql database on a localhost:88

Then

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/basicphp/setData.php");
```

You aren't specifying the port anywhere...

So:

```
Connection to http://10.0.2.2 refused
```

Is because you're trying the wrong port, by default it'll be 80 and not 88.

Comment: I've changed the httpPost to `HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:88/basicphp/setData.php");`
Still the same problem. Logcat:
`09-22 20:02:30.192    2272-2287/my.com.jsontry A/postData﹕ Connection to http://10.0.2.2:88 refused`.

And could you tell me what means this:
`09-22 20:01:22.368    2272-2272/my.com.jsontry E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: Can you access your server from any other device? Trying going to `http://10.0.2.2:88/` on your phone's browser. Your web server may only be allowing local connections, this is a common default.

Comment: No, i can't access the server from my phone. Could you tell me how to allow not only local connections? I have a xampp 3.2.1 package and apache server.

Comment: I don't use xampp personally, but you should have a httpd.conf file somewhere. In there it's most likely mentions the IP `127.0.0.1`, it might be next to a "bind" setting or an "allow from" setting. Change this to 0.0.0.0 which basically allows apache to listen on all interfaces. Confirm that you're using port 88 in your xampp config as well. And also make sure you don't have a firewall on the PC running xampp blocking port 88. In theory that's everything that would get in the way.

Comment: In my httpd.conf I've found this: Listen 88, and also ServerName localhost:88, and nothing else with connected with ip or port.
Changed to ServerName 0.0.0.0:88, didn't work:(